# How can I check if my metadata tags for Google Scholar work?

Tags: meta-tags, structured-data, validation, google-scholar

I’m creating a site where I would like to use tags for indexing my pages on Google Scholar, but I don’t know if my tags works.

Should we use https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ for testing or does another tool exist?

Comment: For reference, here is the documentation for the list of meta tags that Google requires: https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#indexing